# can something have electricity flowing in it without being connected to electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, power-electronics

Can something have a powerful electronic flow throw it that's remain constant for a very long period of time if it was somehow electronically charged before hand?

Comment: ... wat? It's called a battery.

Comment: A superconductor ring will do.

Comment: Well could a device contain a very powerful amounts of electricity? Even stronger then a battery

Comment: @LostPecti You are operating very vague terms.

Comment: Well let's go off of  pipe battery idea. Could we create something like a battery but more powerful and have more electricity flowing through jt

Comment: @LostPecti Two batteries.

Comment: By definition the only device that can both store and use energy is a superconducting ring as mentioned by Eugene.

Comment: Ahem...The superconducting rings of today still need external power to keep them super cold. Changing or charging the magnetic field needs lots of power. No free lunch.

Comment: @Sparky256 Just throw them into a deep space well isolated from external radiations..

Comment: @EugeneSh. That would work. If magnetized then stored on a moon such as Titan...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Two batteries XDXD... How about 3 BATTERIES!? Rechargeable and connected to a super inductive charger??

Comment: Nothing really stores electricity (electricity is more of an umbrella term than a thing - like the word "ambience"), now if you mean something that can electrically charged up and release it's stored *energy* (energy is a thing), then there's a few options. E.g. Batteries are charged by converting electrical energy into chemical potential energy. Someone mentioned superconducting loops, these store energy in magnetic fields (magnetic potential energy). Capacitors can store electrical energy as an electrical charge (electrical potential energy). It stops being potential energy when you use it.

Comment: But if you meant "can something maintain a flow of electrons after being charged up?" Well then, connect any load to something that can store or generate electrical energy and bingo, the electrons will fly 'round until the device is drained (metaphorically speaking, they're actually quite slow most of the time). The superconducting loop is a special case as if left undisturbed (and kept *BLISTERINGLY* cold), electrons can flow in a loop of superconducting wire forever - that's the only time you can get anything to move in a loop, forever... perpetual motion, who said it was impossible (?)

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

This is called a [*battery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_%28electricity%29):

> An electric battery is a device consisting of one ***or more*** electrochemical cells

You can connect as many cells you want in series and parallel and create a battery with any amount of stored energy.

Comment: So the more cells I add the more electricity it can hold thus being more powerful? P.S sorry for the vague terms I and JUST learning and don't understand everything yet

Comment: @LostPecti That's right. The only limit is physical - you need a place to store them.

Comment: But there is no electron flow unless you draw current from the batteries.

Comment: My last question which may sound silly, but let's say the electrons were to collide with other outside atoms and cause a fire should this also destroyed the election atom?

Comment: I heard this happen sometimes when electron pass through wires

Comment: @LostPecti. have you read anything about batteries and volts / current / resistance?

Comment: @LostPecti I think your understanding of electricity should be significantly improved...

Comment: Well that's kind of what I'm trying to do. I thought if you didn't understand something you asked not be bash. My bad I'm not an expert yet I just starting looking into it.. Like today

Comment: @LostPecti This is not a forum, it's is a place with quality answers to quality questions. It is expected that users do some research on their own.

Comment: This is not the right way to learn the basics. The right one would be to read some books or take some classes.

Comment: Well thought I did but didn't understand the term that why I asked.. If I completely understood the research won't need this site

Comment: Not trying to learn all of electrical engineering just certain things for a certain project

Comment: Can't say I encourage such an approach...

Comment: That's a stupid approach.  You don't know enough to ask a question that others can understand.  You don't know enough to understand an answer that others might give you.  Go read AoE.